# Enlarge numuber of items in a EXTJS combo

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have an ExtJs combo with 20 items.

When I open it I get a scroll bar, which I have to scroll to get to the last items on the list.

Does someone know how can I enlarge the number of items the combo can contain on a certain time to 20 (so that I will not have the scroll bar on the side)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try to add this config to your combo.
Here your are increasing the drop down's height there by you can see more options.

```
listConfig:{
        maxHeight:  //Give a value that suits your req. 
      }
```

Refer the docs for further information

Hope it helps you